# Web service returns "Access is denied" for only some requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have an ASP.NET in C# web application which consumes data from a web service. It works                 just fine most of the time, but sometimes, usually when requesting larger data sets, it         only returns an Access is denied error.

For instance, if I call the service to return some documents from between a certain date range, with a small enough range it works just fine. If I expand the range too far, however, it returns this error. This leads me to believe it's either a size or a time issue.

However, if I try to return all of the documents it returns the Access is denied error almost instantly, with no waiting.

I'm pretty certain the problem lies between the service and the app, or even in the configuration of the app.

Can anyone help me discover why I am getting this vague Access is denied error? Let me know if there's more information I should supply.

**Edit:**
I do control the web service.

I've tried calling the service through a little windows form app and I've never seen any errors.

I'm calling the web service via some kind of contract client? I'm not sure of the specifics, but I just have a service reference pointing to the service, and then I am able to declare a client and then use the methods within.

I am able to access the service just fine in the browser.

As far as the other questions go, I'm not sure yet. I'll look into it further.

**Edit 2:**
Here's the config for the Client:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    //omitted
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" maxRequestLength="51200" />
<pages theme="Theme1" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    //omitted 
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<httpHandlers>
    <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
<appSettings>
//omitted
</appSettings>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="DefaultEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:09:00" openTimeout="00:09:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:09:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="DefaultEndpoint1" closeTimeout="00:09:00" openTimeout="00:09:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:09:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="/*omitted*/ " binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" bindingConfiguration="DefaultEndpoint" contract="/*omitted*/ " name="DefaultEndpoint" />
  <endpoint address="/*omitted*/ " binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" bindingConfiguration="DefaultEndpoint1" contract="/*omitted*/ " name="DefaultEndpoint1" />
</client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And here's the config for the service:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=/*omitted*/" >
        <section name="ITSLogger.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=/*omitted*/" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
    <!--<anonymousIdentification enabled="false"/>-->
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="RWS.ServiceImplementation.ResearchService_Behavior"
    name="RWS.ServiceImplementation.ResearchService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="DefaultEndpoint"
      bindingNamespace="http://researchwebservice.model/research" bindingConfiguration="userHttp"
      contract="RWS.ServiceContracts.IResearchServiceContract"/>
    <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="userHttp"
             closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:01:00"
             allowCookies="false"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             messageEncoding="Text"
             textEncoding="utf-8"
             transferMode="Buffered"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="RWS.ServiceImplementation.ResearchService_Behavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ITSLogger.Properties.Settings.ITSLoggerConnectionString"
        connectionString=/*omitted*/
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<applicationSettings>
  <ITSLogger.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="LogFilePath" serializeAs="String">
      <value>C:\ITSLogger\LoggerTest\</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="MailServer" serializeAs="String">
    <value>/*omitted*/</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="MailRecipient" serializeAs="String">
    <value>sklingbeil@itsmtc.com</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="CanLogToEmail" serializeAs="String">
    <value>False</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="CanLogToFlatFile" serializeAs="String">
    <value>False</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="CanLogToTrace" serializeAs="String">
    <value>False</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="CanLogToConsole" serializeAs="String">
    <value>False</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="CanLogToEventLog" serializeAs="String">
    <value>true</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="CanLogToDB" serializeAs="String">
    <value>False</value>
  </setting>
</ITSLogger.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>

<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData= "/*omitted*/" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

I've omitted a few things here and there that I thought might be too revealing.

Comment: Have you written the Web Service yourself?

Comment: More information needed.  do you control the webservice?  Have you tried calling the service from a separate app (like a console app) to test if you can reproduce the issue?  What do you see when running a debugging tool like Fiddler 2?  How are you calling the webservice?  What is the actual HTTP status code that is being returned?  Are you able to access the web service via a browser?

Comment: Is this a WCF Webservice, or an older style .asmx SOAP service?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a WCF service. I could easily be wrong, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be helpful if you can post your  config section from Service and Client config files.

Please refer to maxReceivedMessageSize/ MaxBufferSize / MaxBufferPoolSize properties of a binding and try increasing the values.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx

If possible turn on the WCF Tracing and verify the Request and Response messages.

Comment: I've added the config files and I will take a look at all of the fields you mentioned. Hopefully this will help. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I wasn't able to fix my issue with your suggestions. I think it it a much deeper problem. However, I awarded you the bounty because your answer had the most upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to the web service to obtain debugging information you should take a look at the binary size of the output data you're requesting. There is a finite limit that can be transferred through a web service by default (4096k). You can override this setting by changing the following attribute in the web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="16256" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For web services, I've seen this result in an access denied error. I've never gotten a satisfactory response on why it presents this way rather than by an exception.

Comment: It probably results in an access denied error because request lengths that are too large may be viewed as potential DoS attacks. Thats my guess, anyway.

Comment: @Sean Thoman: That makes sense, and I've seen a few other suggestions indicating that it's protecting the system memory from buffer overflow attacks, network overflow, etc. All of them great ideas, and I'm willing to accept them all as truth because the behavior is consistent :)

Comment: This got my hopes up, but sadly it didn't fix my issue. I wish I could give more details, but I'm so far in over my head here I wouldn't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing between datatypes at your server - where documents are retrieved - . Conversion between data types at server often kills a webservice, mostly due to overflows.